# How can I fix this error: Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-navigation/stack'?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

package.json:

```
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4", 
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
```

MainNavigator:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  createStackNavigator,
  createAppContainer,
} from 'react-navigation/stack';
import HomeScreen from './Surveys'


const Stack = createStackNavigator(MyStack);

function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />

    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

export default createAppContainer(Stack);
```

I have deleted node_modules, npm installed for Expo, installed specifically react-navigation/native, installed specifically react-navigation/stack.. I've gone in circles for an hour on this, nothing fixes it.

Comment: you forgot to add `@` to import  statement. `import {createStackNavigator, createAppContainer} from '@react-navigation/stack';` Also `createAppContainer` is an old usage of react navigation. you need to import `NavigationContainer` from `@react-navigation/native` for version 5 https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started ...Also, `createStackNavigator(MyStack)`? Please read the documentation...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ yarn add react-navigation
$ expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
$ yarn add react-navigation-stack @react-native-community/masked-view
```

```
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
```

Comment: Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-navigation/stack'

Comment: @infinesse after changing packages and import?

Answer (score 0):

i was trying to re-use parts of an old project using old versions of these libraries/components. the solution was to build it from scratch with the current versions, which was very easy/fast. i wasted a few hours, which i guess isn't a total loss because will serve as a reminder that sometimes it is better to just start from scratch.